# Use PHP to generate from an existing database for each row a new specific HTML that i already made

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

First I'm hitting on a wall here and I really could use your help. I **coded the database** so I have it all up and working plus all the data inside. I **worked the HTML and the CSS media print query** and I have it how I want it to look exactly. All I have to do now is:

> for every row of the mysql select table I have to fill every specific input form
>   of the html page I made and print it

Can someone give me a hint of how I can do that?

Comment: what have you done so far?? you need to fetch the data from database and print it out!!

Comment: i wrote below:
it's like generating all the invoices from a shop database that on each row has all the variable for an invoice. when I press button on current page, connect to database, do the query, and for every variable of each row from database, complete the html/input container on external page for every variable and print the page out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to connect to your database and simply fetch the id you can do the following.

Ensure you change `my_host`, `my_user`, `my-password`, `my_databse,`my_table`with your configuration settings. Then if you want to fetch anything else than`id` just change it to the column name you are looking for.

Be aware we are using PHP here.

```
// Open Connection
$con = @mysqli_connect('my_host', 'my_user', 'my-password', 'my_databse');

if (!$con) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

// Some Query
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
$query  = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $row['id'];
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close ($con);
```

Check this [link](http://webdevzoom.com/connect-mysql-database-using-php/) to get a in-depth explanation.

Comment: yeah i did all this to create tables but i don't want to print out the data from there. When I press a button I just want to complete an different html page that has input forms with specific names with every data i found in each row for example: i have name1 name2 number1 number2 columns, i fetch every row and put the result in the input forms i have on that external page. after that i want to print the page because i made a media query to look exactly as i want when i print it. hope it's clearer.

Comment: it's like generating all the invoices from a shop database that on each row has all the variable for an invoice. when I press button on current page , connect to database, do the query, and for every variable of each row from database, complete the html/input container on external page and print the page out.

Comment: Your question is very broad and I cannot understand what is your problem. If you need someone to do what the code for you, this is not the place. If you have already written some code please update your question accordingly and highlight where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two pages. One page gives you the overview and the other page gives you a print preview of your invoice.

The overview:

```
// DB select stuff here

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "    <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['what'])."</td>\n";
    echo "    <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['ever'])."</td>\n";
    echo "    <td><a href=\"detail.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Detail</a></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

The detail page:

```
$sql = 'SELECT your, columns FROM tab WHERE id = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!$row) {
    echo "There is no data for the given Id\n";
    return;
}
echo "What: ".htmlspecialchars($row['what'])."<br />\n";
echo "Ever: ".htmlspecialchars($row['ever'])."<br />\n";
```

Comment: thank you very much. it sounds logical. I'll try making it like your example.